# Eslint shows error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: javascript, eslint, es6-modules

I have a simple HTML + CSS + JS project, where I want to use a JS class. I defined the class as:

```
class Warning {
    constructor(id, className) {
        this.id = id;
        this.className = className;
    }

    add () {
        $(this.id).addClass(this.className);
    }
    remove () {
        $(this.id).removeClass(this.className);
    }
}

export default Warning;
```

and tried to use it in `contact.js`:

```
import Warning from './Warning.js';
const warning = new Warning();
```

However with both `import` and `export`, I got ESLint error:

```
Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

I tried to use `type="module"` where the class is imported, but error is still there:

```
<script src="/static/js/Warning.js" charset="utf-8" type="module"></script>
```

Any idea how I could use the class?

Comment: The script which uses `import` must be the type of module.

Comment: This isn’t about how your HTML loads the module. It’s about how ESLint reads the JS file. Alter your ESLint settings.

Comment: @Teemu I tried adding type module to the script `<script src="/static/js/contact.js" charset="utf-8" type="module"></script>`, but no luck

Comment: Does the code actually work? It seems like it's only your linter that is complaining.